# Expand and collapse Q&A in search results

Tags: feature-request, search

It would be super cool to read the question and answers in a continuous format when searching for a specific tag because this would make it easy for new learners like me while searching for a specific tag for learning purposes instead of opening the questions each and every time.

Answer (score 4):

*Maybe* in the era of IE6 or Netscape, when browsers opened everything in a separate window, and having more than one window open for internet browsing was still relatively niche...but these days, given the proliferation of multiple tabs and tab groups and all other workflow niceties that modern browsers now have as standard, having what should be a list of search results* turn into an expandable set of full questions and answers devoid of other context is not that appealing.

<sup>*: If you search in general, you get both questions *and* answers.  This would only *really* make sense if you only ever got questions as results.</sup>